# Unknown options for package siunitx

Tags: errors, siunitx

I'm getting an error when I try to specify an option with the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. I have the following line in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[load-configurations=si-abbr]{siunitx}
```

And I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `load-configurations' for package `siunitx'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3894 \ifx
           \@empty\si@emulate\@empty\else
? H
The option `load-configurations' was not declared in package `siunitx', perhaps
 you
misspelled its name. Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

I'm not sure which version of `siunitx` I have; I installed it via the `texlive-*` packages in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid). If somebody could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately, the TeX Live/Debian provided with Ubuntu 10.04 is quite old, so the provided **siunitx** lacks that option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have version 1 of `siunitx` installed, and are mixing version one option values (`abbr`) with version 2 key names (`load-configurations`). You want

```
\usepackage[alsoload=abbr]{siunitx}
```

In general, you should check the installed documentation for a package on your local system by typing

```
texdoc <package-name>
```

at the Terminal. This will give you the relevant options for the version you have.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense, and it works now. Thanks a lot.